# Windows Form, wpf mouse click event

Tags: windows

I am new to interface design and I would like to have my own custom software interface. I using C#.net either windows form or wpf.

Let's say I have a background image (the whole interface design), can I detect a certain mouse click event on only a certain area of the background? Like say the "login" button which I drew on background (Not a button control from the framework) so that I make it function like a button.

Or I have to do the background design separately and make the "login" button drawing a picture box control and creating events from there?

Comment: use picturebox .. fill with image button .. on mousehover you can imagebutton

Comment: so I cannot have one whole back ground image with different events all over the picture right. So means every control I must have a separate image to use as picturebox which also means I cannot draw everything on the same background.

Answer (score 0):

Like this ..

[image]

There's form with background image + button image in picturebox (transparent backcolor)

Test with mousehover on the button image

```
Private Sub PictureBox1_MouseHover(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles PictureBox1.MouseHover
   MsgBox("hi")
End Sub
```